# Windows 8 process System takes 100% disk usage and extremly slows pc

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, process, task-manager

I have Windows 8 and recently I have problem with process `System`. Sometimes this process takes disk usage to 100% for a several minutes and working speed is betwenn 0,1MB/s and 0,4MB/s. I can't work with computer and I must wait. It happens after start of the system, from sleep or just after tens of minutes running. There was no problem with this before. Is there any way how can I find out what system is doing? Which task could do this? How to fix this?
Btw I have Acer TimelineX 3820TG.

Comment: Sounds like a hDD problem.

Comment: I have this problem on all my Windows 8 machines, but not from the beginning... as if an update introduced some weird new process

Comment: My problem was really with harddrive so when I change it W8 works normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System` is the Windows kernel. It is not very observable from userspace. This is often caused by:

- Faulty hardware
- A misbehaving driver
- Very inefficient disk storage subsystem stuff (e.g., encrypted software RAID-5)
- A rootkit

The approach to beginning to solve this is incredibly specific to your situation, but in your shoes I'd try a few random things like:

- Running a SMART test on the hard drive
- Booting another operating system using e.g. a Live CD of Linux (Ubuntu, for example) and check out the I/O performance in there to rule out any software or driver issues
- Reinstalling the OS if it does appear to be a software problem
- Replacing hardware if the performance is the same even using another OS

Comment: I think u r right and this would be disk problem. I tried check volume in properties in Windows and CHKDSK after reboot but both stuck at something about 28%. So I'll try to run another program from usb to fix this and maybe reinstall but I think I must replace the harddisk. Just want to ask what's the best utility run from usb for checking and fixing hdd? Thanks